# Implementing permission-based access role in NestJS

Tags: permissions, nestjs, authorization, rbac

I'm working on a NestJS project which requires Permission-based access control.

Most of the functionalities are covered. User's permissions are tied to every request. Routes (or controllers) are decorated with the permission name. If a user doesn't have a permission defined on the route/controller, access is denied. This part is solved via a permission guard.

The case I'm trying to solve is permission-based access in the service layer. A regular user isn't allowed to access all users in the database.

My first attempt would be to check the user's permissions in the service method (e.g. findAll), and if the user's only permitted to read their own entities I would return only that user. Otherwise, all entities are returned. However, for this to work I have to pass the userId and user's permissions from the controller into the service layer. Is there a better way of solving this problem?